# Regex.Replace matching

Tags: c#, regex, json

I'm having some issues with a Json deserializer. One of the values in the returned Json is to large and is throwing exceptions. I actually do not need the info that it is returning so I want to ignore it. I figured the best way to do this would be to search the json string for the attribute, then set the value to null.

Here's a sample of the returned Json that is giving me the error.

```
           "attributes": [
                {
                    "defindex": 143,
                    "value": 2111522248,
                    "float_value": 364329070052570260000000000000
                },
```

I would like to replace the "float_value" attribute(Ie. `36432907005257026000000000`) with an empty value, or nill, so that it does not throw the exception during Json Deserialization.

I'm using `Regex.Replace(json, "\"float_value\": \\d+", String.Empty);`

But it doesn't appear to be removing it, and is still throwing the exception.

Comment: is it the same exception afterwards? because there is trailing comma left in the object after removing the float_value line... preceding the regex by ,?\s* would do the trick

Comment: After getting the Replace to correctly remove the item I wanted, I am indeed getting another error in the Json, which, as you stated, I believe is because the trailing comma on the previous "value" line.

Here's the regex I attempted to use @",?\s""float_value"":\d+"

But it's not working with that either. It's removing the float_value, not for sure about the comma.

Comment: it needs to be @",?\s*""float_value"":\s*\d+" to get any number of whitespace and regex options need to be set to singleline to replace across multiple lines

Comment: I believe that has fixed it for me. Thank you. This issue has been stumping me for 4 days. Couldn't figure out how to fix the Deserialization exception thrown. It doesn't happen after replacing this now.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>When you say `\\d+` you're actually escaping the second `\`, and not indicating that you want a `\d`. Try this instead:</strike>

```
Regex.Replace(json, "\"float_value\": \d+", String.Empty);
```

Here's a breakdown of what you had before. Note the literal `d`: http://www.regex101.com/r/wQ6jD5

Edit: Nvm, this doesn't apply since you were using a normal string rather than a verbatim string. As Jj' indicated, I think the problem is that you have a `,` on the previous line which you didn't remove.

Comment: Using what you provides gives an Unrecognized escape sequence.

Comment: Huh? It works fine for me... http://www.regex101.com/r/cO2wZ2.Is that an unrecognized esape sequence on the regex101 site or in your code?

Comment: Inside Visual Studio. It's giving me an Unrecognized escape sequence.

Comment: Michael, double backslash is correct, when you use a normal string. @user1912335 you should use a verbatim string though (`@"..."`). Within that you don't need to double escape anything any more (and quotes are escaped as `""`.

Comment: @m.buettner Oops. I have no experience with C# and had no idea about normal and verbatim strings.
@user1912335 I think you're problem is the preceding `,` on the previous line as jJ' indicated.